# Limit of Namespaces in Azure Service Bus and Blob Storage

Tags: azure, namespaces, azure-blob-storage, azureservicebus

I will use AzureServiceBus and BlobStorage, both have limit Namespaces, someone could tell me if the namespaces are shared?

For example, if I reach the limit of namespaces in ServiceBus, you can not create new namespaces in BlobStorage?

Comment: Can you please explain your question in more details? Service Bus has namespaces and storage accounts have names.

Comment: So different? I did mess with Namespaces!

Answer (score 0):

Azure **ServiceBus** and Azure **Storage** are two separate services so the quotas and limits are separate. The limits on ServiceBus namespaces per subscription is 100 (detailed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/)). The various limits for Azure Storage are detailed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/).